# How can i get the angle after affine transforming in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, angle, affinetransform

Now I got two sets of corner points from two rectangles and the angle from `rect1`. I have used  `cv::estimateRigidTransform(rect1_coners, rect1_coners);` to calculate the transform matrix.

How can I use the matrix to calculate the `rect2` angle?

[image]

Comment: do you mean the rotation matrix part of the affine transformation or the alignment of a transformed line? Please keep in mind that transforming a rectangle doesnt necessarily result in a rectangle. If you just need the angle of a single line it is ok to transform 2 points on the line and compute their angle to the coordinate system axis

Comment: the question has a broken chain.. if you have the four points if the second rectangle why you want a transformation matrix to solve this problem??

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Because i want to get the angle which cannot get from coner points

Comment: @Micka   the rotation matrix part .Thank you for your comment. But if i do not know the points on line,just the angle value.How can i get the transform angle?

Comment: Google for homography matrix decomposition  But I think if you have your rectangle untransformed you can simply transform the corner vertices.

Comment: @kookoo121 You can get the angle from the corner it is so simple. there is ton of solution fro this. the simplest one is just take a rotated_rect and get the angle from its attributes.. did I miss sth ?